# App compiles fine not errors but then breaks on button click. May have to do with background color change

Tags: java, android, colors, background

The app was running fine before I added the code to change the background color so it has got to be something in there but I am very new to java and Android Studio so I am not sure what.

The app compiles fine but then breaks as soon as I click the button. By breaks I mean it closes on the AVD and I get a dialogue saying the app has stopped. Please help if you can.

```
   package com.example.jacqueline.funfacts;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class FunFactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FactBook factbook = new FactBook();
    private ColorChange colorChange = new ColorChange();
    //Declare our view variables
    private TextView factTextView;
    public Button showFactButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);

        //Assign the views from the layout file to the corresponding variables

        factTextView = findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
        showFactButton = findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);

        View.OnClickListener factListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Get a fact from our FactBook
                String fact = factbook.getFact();

                //Update the screen with our new fact
                factTextView.setText(fact);

                //Change the background color
                colorChange.setColor();
            }
        };
        showFactButton.setOnClickListener(factListener);
    }
}

    package com.example.jacqueline.funfacts;

import java.util.Random;

public class FactBook {
    //Fields or Member Variables - Properties about the object
    private String[] facts = {
            "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
            "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
            "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
            "You are born with 300 bones; by the time you are an adult you will have 206.",
            "It takes about 8 minutes for light from the Sun to reach Earth.",
            "Some bamboo plants can grow almost a meter in just one day.",
            "The state of Florida is bigger than England.",
            "Some penguins can leap 2-3 meters out of the water.",
            "On average, it takes 66 days to form a new habit.",
            "Mammoths still walked the earth when the Great Pyramid was being built." };

    //Methods - Actions the object can take
    public String getFact(){
        //Randomly select a new fact
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(facts.length);
        return facts[randomNumber];
    }
}


    package com.example.jacqueline.funfacts;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ColorChange {
     RelativeLayout layout;
     private int clickCount = 0;
     String[] color = { "#39add1",
                        "#3079ab",
                        "#c25975",
    };

    public void setColor(){
        if (clickCount > 3){
            clickCount = 0;
        }
        String newColor = color[clickCount];
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(newColor));
        clickCount = clickCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You said it breaks but you didn't provide us your exception stacktrace

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know what that is or how to find it. The only error of any kind that I get is the dialogue telling me Fun Facts has stopped working.

Comment: this? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path:

Comment: The relativelayout layout is null in your ColorChange class

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by your `ColorChange.setColor()` method:

```
if (clickCount > 3){
        clickCount = 0;
}
String newColor = color[clickCount];
```

If you connect to your android console, it should say `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception.

Let say your `clickCount = 3`, then the if is passed, the `newColor` will be extracted from `color[3]` which is out of your array bound.

Solution:   `clickCount > 3` to `clickCount > 2` or `clickCount >= 3`

Comment: Thanks, that is a mistake I missed and I have now corrected it. It was not the source of the problem though. It never got to 3 because the app stops working on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
         "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener"
```

the likely explanation is that you have an Android API mismatch.  The [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnUnhandledKeyEventListener) says that that class was added in API level 28.

I suspect that this is unrelated to your problem, but someone would be able to be more definite about that if you posted the **complete** stacktrace.

---

Looking at the `ColorChange` class, I can see three separate bugs:

1. If `clickCount` is 3, `color[clickCount]` will give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.   Array index values go from zero to `array.length - 1`, and the array length is 3 in this case.
2. Since you did not initialize `layout` variable, it will be `null`, and `layout.setBackgroundColor(...)` will throw a `NullPointerException`.
3. This statement does absolutely nothing:

   ```
      clickCount = clickCount++;
   ```

   (Think about it.  Carefully.)